# SSRS Toolbar style / layout

Tags: css, reporting-services, report, toolbar

I have an issue using SSRS when displaying on screen I get it appearing on 3 rows and its a waste of space and I want it all on one row. I cannot see any options of styling the toolbar or configuring it to one row.

It looks like this on all browsers. Is there anything I can do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Just in case someone else gets stuck with this situation, I got it working now by purchasing SSRS 2017 but I had to change a few things.

- All I had to do was change the compatibility of the Report Database from 2008 to 2017 directly inside SQL Manager.

In Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager I uninstalled:

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.VS2010
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.VS2010

Make sure there are no more conflicting reportViewer services installed, I had these installed on mine, this messed me up. Make sure you clean your solution and reboot visual studio.

Then I installed using NuGet Package Manager:

- Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms

Then I went into Web.Config and changed the 10.0.0.0 and tokens to these:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>

<assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
</assemblies>

<buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
</buildProviders>    

<handlers>
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"        type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
</handles>
```

Then the ASPX page you want to use add this to the top removing the old:

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
```

After this is was all golden.

This looks a lot better after the fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have custom parameter layouts when using SSRS 2016.  If you are using a prior version you are stuck with the layout you have.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2015/10/20/position-report-parameters-the-way-you-want/

Comment: Damn, I cant update to that version because of money, is there a workaround.

Comment: Afraid not.  If this is the correct - albeit disappointing - answer to your question, kindly mark it as such for others that have the same issue.

Comment: If you are using the Report Viewer in your own app, you can develop your own parameter selection screen so you don't show the built in one. But if you are using the Report Manager portal then you're stuck with this.

Comment: I had a feeling I would have to do something like that.